# how to write special characters(interpunct) in a xml file in java?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

I have a problem in writing a xml file with UTF-8 in JAVA.
Problem: I have a file with filename having an interpunct(middot)(·) in it. When im trying to write the filename inside a xml tag, using java code i get some junk number like  in filename instead of ·

OutputStreamWriter osw =new OutputStreamWriter(file_output_stream,"UTF8");

Above is the java code i used to write the xmlfile. Can anybody tell me why to understand and sort the problem  ? thanks in advance

Comment: The problem might not be with the code writing the data but with the tool you are using to view it.

Comment: Where you get the character? Read from the dir listing? Or is it present in your code? My answer is for the latter.

Comment: The source for writing the xml is string buffer. I add xml tags and values inside a string buffer and will write in a xml file using the above code. So the character is available in both attribute value of the tag and cdata section also but in different values and format.

Answer (score 2):

Java sources are UTF-16 by default.
If your character is not in it, then use an escape:

```
String a = "\u00b7";
```

Or tell your compiler to use UTF-8 and simply write it to the code as-is.

Comment: Not so. Sources are in the platform encoding that are translated to .class files.

Comment: I have these settings in place but still i have error ..
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
file.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

That character is ASCII 183 (decimal), so you need to escape the character to `&#183;`. Here is a demonstration: If I type **`"&#183;"`** into this answer, I get **"·"**
The browser is printing your character because this web page is XML.

There are utility methods that can do this for you, such as [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library's [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) method, which will correctly and safely escape the entire input.

Comment: There is no ASCII 183. For a numeric character entity, you'd want a Unicode point. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @erickson no I meant exactly what I said. see the edited question that demonstrates the use of `&#183;` right in the answer itself!

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean that you've understood and explained correctly. Numeric character entity references use Unicode code points. 183 is not defined by ASCII, but it is the Unicode coding of the mid-dot.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is a good idea to use UTF-8 everywhere.

The **editor** has to know that the source is in UTF-8. You could use the free programmers editor JEdit which can deal with many encodings.

The **javac** compiler has to know that the java source is in UTF-8. In Java you can use the solution of @OndraŽižka.

This makes for two settings in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create XML by hand. Use a library for the purpose. You are just scratching the surface of the heap of special cases that will break a hand-made solution.

One way, using core Java classes, is to create a DOM, then serialize that using an no-op XSL transform that writes to a `StreamResult`. (if your document is large, you can do something similar by driving a SAX event handler.)

There are many third party libraries that will help you do the same thing very easily.