# Problems with encoding from MySQL to XML to HTML

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm currently making a quiz-game with Construct 2 (HTML5), but I'm getting a problem with encoding when using interpunct (·), also known as middle dot. I'm currently generating an XML document with PHP. Encoding set to UTF-8.

- All my documents is saved as UTF-8.
- I have set MySQL tables to utf8mb4.
- All HTML has meta charset set to UTF-8.
- XML has encoding UTF-8.

If I set `$conn->set_charset("utf8");` in the PHP document, it seems to be OK, but middle dot is returned as `Â·` in my game, but normal if I view the XML in browser.

If I don't set MySQL charset, it works in game, but I can't view it in the browser, but gets an encoding error on the middle dot line.

Comment: Encoding issues are painful things.. This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330226/how-to-write-special-charactersinterpunct-in-a-xml-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Something is not set to utf8/utf8mb4 (or, outside MySQL, UTF-8).  Search for "Mojibake" in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of what probably went wrong.

Or it could be "double encoded".  So please follow the tips there (`SELECT HEX...`) to see if which you have:

```
C382C2B7  double encoding - bad
C2B7      utf8 -- should see this
B7        latin1 -- should not see this
```